# how to dockerize a flutter environment in a image and connect to the external emulator

Tags: android, docker, flutter

Is there any way that we can dockerize a flutter environment in a docker image and check the app result in the android emulator , where emulator is run externally not in the docker image

Answer (score 0):

Run below commands one at a time. Note that your computer and your Android Device have to be on the same network.

adb kill-server
adb tcpip 5555
adb connect 10.100.68.106:5555
adb devices